# Any reason this little piece of html/css doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

This code doesn't work and I can't understand why..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.class1{ float:left; margin:10px; background:#09C; width:100px; height:100px; cursor:pointer;}
.class2{ float:left; margin:10px; background:#0C0; width:100px; height:100px; cursor:pointer; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="class 1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
<div class="class 1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
<div class="class 1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
<div class="class 1" onclick="toggleClass(this)"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please past the code snippet as text in your question (no need for image), so that we can copy/past and test, also include the javascript and tell us what exactly is not working

Comment: define "doesnt work". it might as well be working perfectly, just not the way you want it to.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use spaces in class names, `<div class="class 1"` will be interpreted as a div with two classes `class` and `1`.

Comment: Ah it was something that simple.. Thank you I completely missed that.

Comment: welcome, why i was down voted? :)

Comment: a space within the class tag is valid html as you can add multiple classes. In this case there are two classes, one called `class` and the other `1`. Although saying that the class of `1` is invalid as a class must start with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z).

Comment: you're right, i was just unclear, i wanted to say that class name can't be used with space inside :) so it's fine to use 'class_1' but not 'class 1' as name of the class.